# how to check for a sub_string in a string using python?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, string-length

I am provided a string and a substring in python. I have to check how many times the substring appears in the string. My input is the string and substring. My output should be the number of appearances.

**Input:**

string: ABCDCDC

substring: CDC

**Output:**
2

Here's what I did:

```py
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    string_length = len(string)
    for i in range(0, string_length):
        print(string[i], end="")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_string = input().strip()
    
    count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
    print(count)
```

**The Output:**

ABCDCDCNone

I also tried to use the .count function but it only sees one appearance of the sub_string and not 2.

It got me the text but I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: In particular, look at the answers below the top one, which deal with overlapping substrings.

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses regex with a positive lookahead `(?=CDC)`:

```py
import re

inp = "ABCDCDC"
count = len(re.findall(r'(?=CDC)', inp))
print(count)  # 2
```

This regex trick works correctly even with overlapping substrings.  This is because positive lookaheads *match* but do not *consume*.